# image file names adding +

Tags: file-uploads

I have a site that was just updated to EE 2.5.3 and since then it looks like any image I had in a file field that had spaces in the file name now appears to have + in place of the space.  THis has caused all the image sources to be broken.

ie: an image with the name file name.jpg that was uploaded  now appears to be file+name.jpg so the image is broken when viewed in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in 2.5.3 that was fixed.

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/18289

Comment: If that solves the problem for you, please consider accepting your answer as solution. So question looks resolved for others. ;o)

Comment: I wish I could, but it says I cannot accept my answer for 20 hours